# What's Pycharm's default theme?

Tags: pycharm, themes, rstudio

I am trying to reproduce Pycharms default (Color-) theme in RStudio. To do so I need to know its name. According to Pycharms settings it seems to be (some kind of) "Dracula". But at least it does seem to be "standard" Dracula, compare here: https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Dracula.

Does anyone what theme it is if not "standard" Dracula?

Comment: Ah just noticed myself the misread. It's Darcula (sic!) not to confuse with Dracula (notice the slightly different spelling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you are asking, but the default dark theme in PyCharm and other IntelliJ-based products is called "Darcula" (Editor -> Color Scheme)

There is also Darcula implementations available for Netbeans and other IDEs on the [Official Darcula Theme Repository](https://github.com/bulenkov/Darcula).